# How to insert an element in Queue in c using linked implementation

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I tried a basic queue program in c using linked implementation. But it shows some error with the function that is used to insert element to the queue. Also i want to display the element in the queue. Below is the code i tried. The CLI exits when the compiler comes to the Insert() function which i used to insert the element. Also I want to make sure that the method i used to display the element is right or wrong.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef int QueueElement;
typedef enum{FALSE,TRUE} Boolean;
typedef struct node{
    QueueElement data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;
typedef struct queue{
    Node *rear;
    Node *front;
    Boolean Full;
    int count;
}Queue;
void CreateQueue(Queue *q){
    q->count = 0;
    q->Full = FALSE;
    q->front = q->rear = NULL;
}
Boolean IsQueueEmpty(Queue *q){
    return(q->front == NULL && q->rear == NULL);
}
Boolean IsQueueFull(Queue *q){
    return(q->Full);
}
void Insert(QueueElement x, Queue *q){
    Node *np;
    np = (Node* )malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(np == NULL){
        printf("Memory is Full\n");
        q->Full = TRUE;
    }
    np->data = x;
    np->next = NULL;
    if(IsQueueEmpty(q))
        q->front = q->rear = np;
    else{
        q->rear->next = np;
        q->rear = np;
    }
    q->count++;
}
void Remove(QueueElement *x, Queue *q){
    Node *np;
    if(IsQueueEmpty(q))
        printf("Queue is Empty\n");
    else{
        q->count--;
        *x = q->front->data;
        np = q->front;
        q->front = q->front->next;
        if(q->front == NULL)
            q->rear = NULL;
        free(np);
    }
}
int main(){
    Queue q;
    Insert(21,&q);
    int n;
    Remove(&n,&q);
    printf("%d ",n);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Queue q;
Insert(21,&q);
```

After you declare `q` you are supposed to call `createQueue` function to initialize `count, rear and front` pointers.

```
 Queue q;
 CreateQueue(&q);
 Insert(21,&q);
```

Otherwise they will have indeterminate values.

---

Function to display the queue.

```
void Display(Queue q) {
  Node *iter = q.front;

   while(iter) {
      printf("%d ", iter->data);
      iter = iter->next;
   }   
}
```

Call it as below from `main`.

```
Display(q);
```

Comment: Ya i made that silly mistake..is there any other methods to display the elements in the queue using linked list